# angular directives updating child

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives and I am trying to update the child directive depending upon the value change in the parent one.

```
commonApp.directive('osMsgBody', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^osSendMessage',
    scope: {
        body: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {

    $scope.tinymceOptions = {
            resize: false,
            height: 300,
            entity_encoding: "raw"
            //plugins: 'print textcolor',
            //toolbar: "undo redo styleselect bold italic print forecolor backcolor"

        };
```

I am trying to change from tinymye to normal text area depending upon a property in the osSendMessage directive.

```
<div os-msg-body body="msg.body" isSms="{{isSmsMessageTextAreaIsShown}}" class="sendmessages__content__tinymce"></div>
```

I am calling msMsgBody directive like above. Any thoughts? I am very new to angular, this is a quick fix I need to make. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are (probably) having reference problems.
Basically you have 
object a { property: 'something'}
and then you are saying i want to watch the value 'something'.
then you change property, but the value 'something' hasnt changed. so no changes occur
try passing the whole object and look at specific property.
or turn the value you are turning into an object ( {} ).

Comment: if this doesnt help you then i might have understood the question incorrectly, so sorry... and please clarify so i can help :)